# Не может найти нужную строку регулярное выражение

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой код:

```
$url = '[LAST]1[/LAST]'; 
var_dump(preg_match('/\[LAST\]*\[\/LAST\]/', $url,$array));
```

Он должен получить внутренности `[LAST][/LAST]`

Отдает `0` или простыми словами `false`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: поменяйте звездочку на точку

Comment: @splash58 Работает,но отдает не внутренности,а всю строку...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
var_dump(preg_match('/\[LAST\](.*)\[\/LAST\]/', $url,$array));
```

Comment: Я бы уменьшил жадность квантификатора: `/\[LAST\](.*?)\[\/LAST\]/`